# How to send '-X POST' request using 'requests' library in Python?

Tags: python, curl, python-requests

I am trying to replicate shell command:

```
curl -X POST -u 'user:pass' https://databricksda.kdc.capitalone.com/api/1.2/commands/execute -d 'language=scala&clusterId=123&contextId=456&command=sc.parallelize(1 to 5).collect;'
```

into Python code using Requests library:

```
import requests
```

What is a proper syntax for this example (curl -X POST)?

Answer (score 3):

Once you import the `requests` , convert the data being passed to an Object/dictionary and make the POST request. Here's the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests)

```
import requests

data = {
  'language': 'scala',
  'clusterId': '123',
  'contextId': '456',
  'command': 'sc.parallelize(1 to 5).collect;'
}

requests.post('https://databricksda.kdc.capitalone.com/api/1.2/commands/execute', data=data, auth=('user', 'pass'))
```